# included bottom layout for all the android activites with onclick events not working

Tags: android, inheritance, scrollview, onclicklistener

I am new to android development. I want to  include the same horizontal Scroll view in all android activities.I have defined the layout and Onclick events in one separate activity and extended that class with other activites.But the onclick events are not working

**here is my Base Activity**

```
public class Footer extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ImageView img_school, img_group, img_news, img_schemes, img_jobs, img_gallery, img_goddess, img_services, img_census, img_address, img_abt_us;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.imgs_school:
                Intent i = new Intent(Footer.this, SchoolActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.imgs_galary:
                Intent gi = new Intent(Footer.this, GalleryActivity.class);
                startActivity(gi);
                break;
            case R.id.imgs_events:
                Intent ni = new Intent(Footer.this, EventsActivity.class);
                startActivity(ni);
                break;
            case R.id.imgs_abtus:
                break;
            case R.id.imgs_jobs:
                Intent ji = new Intent(Footer.this, JobsActivity.class);
                startActivity(ji);
                break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_footer);
        initAll();
        img_gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
        img_school.setOnClickListener(this);
        img_news.setOnClickListener(this);
        img_jobs.setOnClickListener(this);
        img_abt_us.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void initAll() {

        img_school = findViewById(R.id.imgs_school);

        img_news = findViewById(R.id.imgs_events);
        img_jobs = findViewById(R.id.imgs_jobs);
        img_gallery = findViewById(R.id.imgs_galary);
        img_abt_us = findViewById(R.id.imgs_abtus);
    }
}
```

**and the XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgs_school"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/school"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_35sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="School"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgs_events"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/news"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_35sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Events"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgs_jobs"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/jobs"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_35sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Jobs"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgs_galary"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/gallery"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_35sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Gallery"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/imgs_abtus"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/abt_us"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_35sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="About Us"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And i am extending this activity with other classes

such as

```
public class SchoolActivity extends Footer {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_school);
    }
}
```

And its activity_school xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.evoqis.manovaru.SchoolActivity">

<include layout="@layout/activity_footer"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But the onclick events are not happening.
Thanks in adavance

Comment: sjow your `activity_school`. ALso why don't you just use different fragments instead of activities?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: ok, I see the problem now. I will give an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem:

In subclass you call:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Which calls:-

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_footer); //which creates a new views    
initAll(); //which finds views by id    
img_gallery.setOnClickListener(this); //setting listeners.
```

and then in subclass you call:
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_school);` which **creates new view**, and overrides all the listeners you have set in superclass.

**How to fix it**

Move

```
    img_gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
    img_school.setOnClickListener(this);
    img_news.setOnClickListener(this);
    img_jobs.setOnClickListener(this);
    img_abt_us.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Inside `public void initAll()`, and in subclass do this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_school);
initAll();
```

Also you can remove `onCreate()` method from superclass.

Comment: so what should i do